# HTML Editor and Substring in PHP

Tags: php, html, tinymce

I am using TINY MCE editor for editing/adding text/description about project in php mysql database of a php project management application. Admin can add    and other html entities using that editor.. for example

```
<table><tr><td>...blah blah text entered....</td></tr></table>
```

when I substr this , suppose I substing from 0 to 10 then it result in problem as the table starts but not end....

can anybody please suggest the ideal way for resolving this.....?

Edits : I want to show a part of this text which is saved in database...

Comment: what is you goal? why to substring?

Comment: I want to show a part of this text which is saved in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the PHP function above. The HTML tags will be considered.

```
function truncate($text, $length = 100, $ending = '...', $exact = false, $considerHtml = true) {
    if ($considerHtml) {
            if (strlen(preg_replace('/<.*?>/', '', $text)) <= $length) {
                    return $text;
            }

            preg_match_all('/(<.+?>)?([^<>]*)/s', $text, $lines, PREG_SET_ORDER);
            $total_length = strlen($ending);
            $open_tags = array();
            $truncate = '';
            foreach ($lines as $line_matchings) {
                    if (!empty($line_matchings[1])) {
                            if (preg_match('/^<(\s*.+?\/\s*|\s*(img|br|input|hr|area|base|basefont|col|frame|isindex|link|meta|param)(\s.+?)?)>$/is', $line_matchings[1])) {
                            } else if (preg_match('/^<\s*\/([^\s]+?)\s*>$/s', $line_matchings[1], $tag_matchings)) {
                                    $pos = array_search($tag_matchings[1], $open_tags);
                                    if ($pos !== false) {
                                    unset($open_tags[$pos]);
                                    }
                            } else if (preg_match('/^<\s*([^\s>!]+).*?>$/s', $line_matchings[1], $tag_matchings)) {
                                    array_unshift($open_tags, strtolower($tag_matchings[1]));
                            }
                            $truncate .= $line_matchings[1];
                    }
                    $content_length = strlen(preg_replace('/&[0-9a-z]{2,8};|&#[0-9]{1,7};|[0-9a-f]{1,6};/i', ' ', $line_matchings[2]));
                    if ($total_length+$content_length > $length) {
                            $left = $length - $total_length;
                            $entities_length = 0;
                            if (preg_match_all('/&[0-9a-z]{2,8};|&#[0-9]{1,7};|[0-9a-f]{1,6};/i', $line_matchings[2], $entities, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
                                    foreach ($entities[0] as $entity) {
                                            if ($entity[1]+1-$entities_length <= $left) {
                                                    $left--;
                                                    $entities_length += strlen($entity[0]);
                                            } else {
                                                    break;
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                            $truncate .= substr($line_matchings[2], 0, $left+$entities_length);
                            break;
                    } else {
                            $truncate .= $line_matchings[2];
                            $total_length += $content_length;
                    }
                    if($total_length >= $length) {
                            break;
                    }
            }
    } else {
            if (strlen($text) <= $length) {
                    return $text;
            } else {
                    $truncate = substr($text, 0, $length - strlen($ending));
            }
    }
    if (!$exact) {
            $spacepos = strrpos($truncate, ' ');
            if (isset($spacepos)) {
                    $truncate = substr($truncate, 0, $spacepos);
            }
    }
    $truncate .= $ending;
    if($considerHtml) {
            foreach ($open_tags as $tag) {
                    $truncate .= '</' . $tag . '>';
            }
    }
    return $truncate;
}

$str = '<table><tr><td>...blah blah text entered....</td></tr></table>';

print truncate($str, 10, '', true, true);
// will output: <table><tr><td>...blah bl</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: This seems horribly inefficient to accomplish such a simple task.

Answer (score 0):

Use [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) first, to remove the html, and then use `substr` to get the first 10 characters of the result. You will then have a plain-text version of the text.

Also note that it is wise to have text without escaped entities. For instance, `C'est privé` instead of `C'est priv&eacute;`, or else you can still end up with a text like `C'est priv&eac`, which will also look like garbage.

The best is to store and process the unescaped values, but if you do have escaped data, you can use [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) to convert the html escape sequences to their actual characters.